# Trying to add hCaptcha to my site but don't understand this javascript code

Tags: javascript, html, forms

Javascript isn't really my strong point. I already have the php working for the captcha on the backend but i want to be able to validate the form with JS to prevent the user from sending a form when the captcha hasn't been completed.

This is the example the hcaptca site gives:
https://medium.com/@hCaptcha/using-hcaptcha-with-php-fc31884aa9ea

And here is the JS code they give as an example.

```
$("form").submit(function(event) {

   var hcaptchaVal = $('[name=h-captcha-response]').value;
   if (hcaptchaVal === "") {
      event.preventDefault();
      alert("Please complete the hCaptcha");
   }
});
```

I'm not 100% sure but that appears to be Jquery and my site does not use Jquery. so i need a vanilla JS solution.

Comment: Have you tried to convert it to vanilla JS yourself? You're much more likely to elicit help that way.

Comment: Yes. i tired doing "document.getElementById("form").value but that "name=h-captca-response" seems to be a JS object or something. it's not something you can access from the DOM.

Comment: What led you to that conclusion? Sure it is. It's not an object, just a selector, and you can do those in both jQuery and vanilla JS. Meet [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

Comment: Could i do:  var e = document.querySelector('[name=h-captcha-response]').value  ?

Comment: @Skilo83 - sorry, a non-SO discussion - how has your experience with hCaptcha? Do you use the free version? Does it work well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me try to explain:

```
$("form").submit(function(event) { }
// When the form is submitted
```

```
var hcaptchaVal = $('[name=h-captcha-response]').value;
// Retrieve the value of the captcha (= the value of an HTML element with the tag name="h-captcha-response"
```

```
if (hcaptchaVal === "") {
   event.preventDefault();
   alert("Please complete the Captcha");
}
// If the value of the captcha is empty, stop the form submission and alert the user
```

So if you are searching for a Vanilla JS solution, it's not that hard, all you have to do is convert the jQuery parts :

```
document.querySelector("#yourFormId").addEventListener("submit", function(event) {

   var hcaptchaVal = document.querySelector('[name="h-captcha-response"]').value;
   if (hcaptchaVal === "") {
      event.preventDefault();
      alert("Please complete the hCaptcha");
   }
});
```

Comment: Nice. This looks like exactly what i need. Thanks. I will try out the code when i get to my dev machine and select your answer as the best one.